# Adobe flash action script 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm a newbie in this field, I'm going to make a mobile course-ware app using ActionScript 3 (Flash).

There will be a quiz section where the student need to answer it and their marks will appear after they finish the quiz. This is also a part of my preparation since I'll be graduating as a teacher soon.

**Question**: 
How to implement a notification message whenever a user logs into the app?

It should notify me the **user name** that logs in. Another way I was thinking is to somehow link the app with Excel so that while user logs in, their name  will appear in Excel document and includes their marks.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [help/on-topic], [help/dont-ask], [mcve].

Comment: Flash is dead. Will any modern iOS and Android device run Flash now anyway? Apple has blocked Flash in Safari for years, and Chrome blocks it by default as well.

Comment: @Amanina, make a list on paper of the app features and then use Google to reseach the possiblities. For notifications part, one way is to get the app to send an email to you, or else if you have some PHP-enabled web space then tell app to talk to a PHP script (where that script updates a database/text file online that has all the users marks).

Comment: @mrunion, you've misunderstood that this is not about browser plugins. You can use also use Flash to create installable desktop/mobile apps. Just like Java is dead (on browser) but you can still create Android apps with it. Same thing with AS3 language.

Comment: Aaaaand that is why Adobe renamed the Flash IDE to Animate. The name "Flash" is too deep-seated in people's minds as the dead browser plugin. (I say this as someone who shipped a browser game written in AS3 just a month ago.)

Comment: @VC.One Thank you for the clarification. I did indeed misunderstand.

Answer (score 1):

You need your app to connect to some sort of web app. So the procedure briefly is like: Students log-on into the app > App tells the server that who (when, with what mark) have logged-on > Server notifies you of all the events.

If you are not an expert programmer I don't suggest you do that on your own, because there's a lot to learn. In addition to developing your as3 app, you need skills in server-side programming languages like PHP or NodeJS or... and probably you will need to do some Database works.

Comment: Oh..thanks for answering. I will not do it since I'm not an expert. :)

Comment: But can I ask another thing regarding to convert my adobe flash file into .apk? Actually I already convert my flash file into .apk, and I already have that .apk file but when I install it into my phone there will be a pop up message saying that my apps is not working. Do you know where might be the problem?